# Windows equivalent for Linux command grep -A (return rows after the search string)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following data in text file and I would like to get Hostname for particular "Node name":

```
Node 1 entry:

 Node name                      = NODE1
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = 192.168.100.1

Node 2 entry:

 Node name                      = NODE2
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = 192.168.100.2

Node 3 entry:

 Node name                      = NODE3
 Comment                        =
 Directory entry type           = LOCAL
 Protocol                       = TCPIP
 Hostname                       = 192.168.100.3
```

SAMPLE: As input I have "Node name" e.g. NODE2. Then I need to search 4 rows bellow NODE2 and read Hostname that is 192.168.100.2. The line with IP address is the result I want.

On Linux it is easy:

```
grep -A 4 "NODE3" file.txt | grep Hostname
```

Note: -A 4 is for return line that matches the search and additional 4 lines

or even better:

```
grep -A 4 "\<NODE3\>" file.txt | grep Hostname
```

if NODE3 would be substring of name like: NODE3A, above command would search strictly for "NODE3" only.

or to only get IP address (third column is one-or-more spaces are delimiter between columns):

```
grep -A 4 "\<NODE3\>" file.txt | grep Hostname | gawk '{print $3}'
```

Question: How to do the same thing on Windows using Windows native commands?

P.S. This script will gonna run on several Windows machines and I DO NOT WANT to install additional software on Windows. I know I can install grep and other commands, but I don't want to. Solution must use Windows only commands (Windows 7, Windows 2008 and newer should be working), because script file (batch file) is going to be run on several different versions of Windows, that I am not allow to install software and also I don't want to distribute other additional software.

Comment: There is no native `grep` equivalent for Windows Command Prompt. You could try batch-parsing line by line through `findstr` but that will be one long-ass batch script and it will depend on what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@echo off

set "skip="
set "host="
set "searchNode=NODE2"

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type file.txt ^| find /I /N "%searchNode%"') do (
  if not defined skip set/a skip=%%A & goto :found
)
:found
if not defined skip echo/%searchNode% was not found. & exit/B

rem lines_to_skip = line_found + lines_below - 1
set /a skip+=3 
for /F "skip=%skip% tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('type file.txt ^| find /N /V "^"') do (
  for /F "tokens=1,* delims== " %%a in ("%%B") do set "host=%%b" & goto :stop
)
:stop
echo/%host%
exit/B
```

First, search the file until the desired string is matched, and store the line number. Then, compute lines to skip (we search for fourth line, so is line number + 4 - 1). Finally, reparse the file reading only the desired line.

Comment: Excellent works fine. (I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer or accept it as correct on).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** streamlined a bit (removed one If)

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem pass Node name as Arg1 to this batch
Set "Node=" & Set "IP=not found"
For /F "tokens=1-3delims=:= " %%A in ('type file.txt') Do (
  If /i "%%A%%B" Equ "Nodename" Set "Node=%%C"
  IF /i "%%A%~1" Equ "Hostname!Node!" Set "IP=%%B"
)
Echo IP for Node %1 is %IP%
```

Sample output

```
> SO_45031925.cmd Node2
IP for Node Node2 is 192.168.100.2

> SO_45031925.cmd Node1
IP for Node Node1 is 192.168.100.1

> SO_45031925.cmd Node3
IP for Node Node3 is 192.168.100.3

> SO_45031925.cmd Node4
IP for Node Node4 is not found
```

---

Sidenote(s) :
with grep and gawk present in windows only the single quotes have to be exchanged with double ones:

```
> grep -A 4 "\<NODE3\>" file.txt | grep Hostname | gawk "{print $3}"
192.168.100.3
```

This PowerShell variant requires Select-String only present in more recent Windows versions.

```
$Node = 'Node3'
$IP = Select-String -Path .\file.txt -Pattern "Node name\s+= $Node" -Context 0,4 |
    ForEach-Object {($_.Context.PostContext[3]).Split('=')[1].Trim()}
"IP for Node {0} is {1}" -f $Node,$IP
```

Comment: Excellent works fine. (I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer or accept it as correct on).

Answer (score 1):

The [SETX command](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) was designed with the purpose of define persistent variables in the cmd.exe environment. However, this command have an unusual and practically unused feature that allows to extract items from a text file that are located in a relative position from other item. The net effect is similar to combine a FOR command with a FINDSTR one, but with additional capabilities and in a much simpler way.

The result you want in your example can be obtained in this way:

```
setx /F test.txt dummyVar /R 4,-1 NODE2
```

In previous line the `/F test.txt` part specify the file to search and the `dummyVar` is the persistent variable to set. The `/R 4,-1 NODE2` part means: "perform a /Relative search of NODE2 item and, after it was found, return the item located 4 lines below and 1 item before". The "items" are numbered starting at zero and are separated by spaces by default, but you may define a series of delimiters via /D switch (similar to "delims=" switch of `for` command). The result is displayed in this way:

```
Extracted value: 192.168.100.2.
```

So, in order to get the result you want, you must use this code:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('setx /F test.txt dummyVar /R 4^,-1 NODE2') do set "host=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
set "host=%host:~0,-1%"
echo %host%
```

Note that the comma in `/R 4,-1` part must be escaped with a caret and that the result includes an additional point at end that must be removed.

A minor disadvantage of this method is that the `dummyVar` is permanently defined in the cmd.exe environment, but this point does not affect cmd.exe operation in any way.

Tested on Windows XP and 8.1. This management is fully described at [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5083).

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, here's a slightly different idea: **greb.cmd**

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
If Not "%~1"=="-A" Exit/B
Set "LB=%~2" & Set "VD=%~3" & Set "FN=%~4"
If Not Exist "%FN%" Exit/B
Set "LN=%LB%"
For /F "Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/IN "\<%VD%\>" "%FN%"') Do Set/A LN+=%%A
If %LN% Equ %LB% Exit/B
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('"FindStr/N $ "%FN%"|FindStr/B "%LN%:""'
) Do For /F %%C In ("%%B") Do Echo(The value data %LB% lines below %3 is %%C
```

To get the value data 4 lines below \<NODE3\> within MyFile.txt, use:

```bat
greb -A 4 NODE3 MyFile.txt
```

…where `greb` and `MyFile.txt` should be full paths or relative to the current directory and double quoted as necessary.

You can edit the string after `Echo(` to suit your required output.